# Scroll to component inside dialog on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I have a JSF/Primefaces page with a long content, which is handled by a scrollbar, and a dialog with a long content with a scrollbar too.
The dialog contains a button and I would like to scroll the dialog content to a certain component inside the dialog (almost on the bottom of it), but if I use

```
PrimeFaces.current().scrollTo("component");
```

the scrolling has effect on the bottom page and not inside the dialog.
By reading other questions I tried to achieve the effect with JQuery by placing a script directly on the button onclick

```
$('#dialog').animate({scrollTop: $('#dialogForm\\:panelDialog').offset().top},'slow');
```

but it's not working.
Following are the files for a minimal (not) working example.

XHTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>
    <p:commandButton value="Basic" type="button" onclick="PF('dialogVar').show();" />
    <p:commandButton value="Scroll" actionListener="#{testCBean.onClick()}" />
    <p:panel>
        <ui:repeat var="item" value="#{testCBean.tableRows}">
            <div>
                #{item}
            </div>
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:panel>
    <p:outputPanel id="panel">
                scroll destination
            </p:outputPanel>
    <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dialogVar" minHeight="40" height="500">
        <h:form id="dialogForm">
            <p:commandButton value="Scroll" actionListener="#{testCBean.onClickDialog()}" />
            <ui:repeat var="item" value="#{testCBean.tableRows}">
                <div>
                    #{item}
                </div>
            </ui:repeat>
            <p:outputPanel id="panelDialog">
                scroll destination
            </p:outputPanel>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Bean:

```
package controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.PrimeFaces;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TestCBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<String> tableRows;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        tableRows = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            tableRows.add("Test");
        }
    }

    public List<String> getTableRows() {
        return tableRows;
    }

    public void setTableRows(List<String> tableRows) {
        this.tableRows = tableRows;
    }

    public void onClick() {
        PrimeFaces.current().scrollTo("panel");
    }

    public void onClickDialog() {
        PrimeFaces.current().scrollTo("dialogForm:panelDialog");
//      PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("$('#dialog').animate({scrollTop: $('#dialogForm\\:panelDialog').offset().top},'slow');");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a way of doing this through JQuery, by using this script:

```
function dialogScroll(dialogId, elementId) {
    $('#' + dialogId).find('.ui-dialog-content').first().animate({scrollTop: $('#' + elementId).offset().top},'slow');
}
```

First argument is the id of the dialog, which is used as a container to find the element you want to scroll to, whose id is passed as second parameter.
This function can then be called directly in the button onclick, or in a java bean method in this way:

```
PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("dialogScroll('dialog', 'dialogForm\\\\:panelDialog');");
```

Note the escape in the element id, necessary if it contains a ":"